# Basketball post up - offensive fouls question

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

I'm watching some of the videos here:

https://videorulebook.nba.com/rule/back-downs/

It seems to me that whenever a defender legitimately falls down (not a flop), while defending the post an offensive foul is called.

So couldn't a defensive player just stand his ground and let himself get tipped over.

Reason I ask is... I see a lot of post ups where the offensive player "backs in" little by little... why give up room like this? If the defensive player stood his ground and let himself fall, wouldn't he get the call? Are defenders just afraid of falling down? Or would the refs just call this as a flop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offensive fouls for this situation are granted when the offensive player makes a sudden, forceful move. A good defender senses such a move and will usually embellish the action of falling back from from the sudden move.

If the movement of the offensive player is only on the order of a simple bump, embellishing the falling movement will be seen as a flop. This will usually result in a no-call, and the offensive player can successfully continue.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but it would be better with information from a reliable source to back it up.

Comment: You won't find this information in any rule book.  This is from years of experience in playing and watching basketball.  Frankly, it's common sense.

Comment: We prefer to avoid "common sense" answers, if possible, as they tend to vary - in particular in things like rules interpretations; it is also helpful to show posters where to find information and how to read it.  This answer could easily be supplemented by rules interpretations and/or rules themselves, even if this explicit answer isn't contained in them - simply the information of what the definition of a personal foul is I suspect would aid in explaining this.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear, I'm not talking about a flop. I'm talking about something like a hard screen. Someone just stands his ground like a statue... So he either stays there or tips over like a statue. Now the defender could back himself up during bumps to maintain his balance and not fall over... So I assume the defender needs to put up some kind of "reasonable effort" to maintain balance by backing up? Otherwise it will be considered a flop?

Comment: That's a different question than what you asked here.  If you have a different question it needs to be asked separately (not this page)